# How to use jQuery's drop event to upload files dragged from the desktop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to use jQuery's `drop` event for dragging files from the desktop?

If so, how do I get the dropped file data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [html5's file api example with jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722500/html5s-file-api-example-with-jquery)

Answer (score 163, accepted):

It's a little messy (you need to handle at least 3 events) but possible.

First, you need to add eventhandlers for `dragover` and `dragenter` and prevent the default actions for these events like that:

```
$('#div').on(
    'dragover',
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
)
$('#div').on(
    'dragenter',
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
)
```

It's actually important to call `preventDefault` on these events, otherwise, some browsers may never trigger the `drop` event.

Then you can add the drop-handler and access the dropped files with `e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files`:

```
$('#div').on(
    'drop',
    function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer && e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            /*UPLOAD FILES HERE*/
            upload(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
        }
    }
);
```

Now you are able to drag files from the desktop/explorer/finder in the div and access them.

http://jsfiddle.net/fSA4N/5/

Comment: Why do you need to suppress default dragover and dragenter behavior?

Comment: Some browsers do some weird things when you start dragging a file into the browser. It's not really necessary. With these events, you could also add some nice features like highlighting the div where you have to drop the file.

Comment: is it possible to somehow use e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files and set it to file input?

Comment: You said "not easy" ...? Your reply solved my same problem instantly!
@loostro: what is possble is to have a "global" var called "file", and use $(':file').change() i.c.w. e.target.files[0] (works for me), or maybe $('this').val();

Comment: @Chris By default, data/elements cannot be dropped in other elements. To allow a drop, we must prevent the default handling of the element. This is done by calling the event.preventDefault()

Comment: Further to 'some browsers do some weird things': if you miss your drag target with, say, an image file drag, the default behaviour for some browsers e.g. Firefox is to open the file in the window. To circumvent this, bind the document body to the dragover and drop events and cancel them (with preventDefault/stopPropagation).

Comment: [Here](http://hayageek.com/drag-and-drop-file-upload-jquery/) is an example how it works and put together for you!