# AngularJS file drag and drop in directive

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This example does pretty much what I would like to port in Angular-js: [HTML5 File API](http://html5demos.com/file-api#view-source).

I have been trying to google some example of directives however I found old example that do massive use of DOM or are not written for Angular 1.0.4.

Basically this is the pure js code:

```
var holder = document.getElementById('holder'),
    state = document.getElementById('status');

if (typeof window.FileReader === 'undefined') {
  state.className = 'fail';
} else {
  state.className = 'success';
  state.innerHTML = 'File API & FileReader available';
}

holder.ondragover = function () { this.className = 'hover'; return false; };
holder.ondragend = function () { this.className = ''; return false; };
holder.ondrop = function (e) {
  this.className = '';
  e.preventDefault();

  var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0],
      reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    holder.style.background = 'url(' + event.target.result + ') no-repeat center';
  };
  console.log(file);
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  return false;
};
```

The only possible way I can think of is creating a directive that does

```
edo.directive('fileDrag', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem) {
      elem.bind('ondrop', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0], reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (event) {
          console.log(event.target);
          holder.style.background = 'url(' + event.target.result + ') no-repeat center';
        };
        console.log(file);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        return false;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

However (1) it did not work, (2) before I fix it I would like to know if something exists or if I am doing it properly,

Any hint or help is very much appreciated.

Comment: what didn't work about it?

Comment: apparently elem.bind('drop') is not working. :/

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544977/using-jquery-on-for-drop-events-when-uploading-files-from-the-desktop you need to prevent defaults in the other two drag events. In the example pasted in this answer, just replace `$('#div')` with `element` I also recommend usong `on` rather than bind. It works just the same way as bind.

Comment: is .on included in angular?

Comment: oh yea, I guess it's not, in that case, carry on with `bind` :)

Comment: I think you have to define `holder`.  Can it be just `elem`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To consolidate the comments into an answer, change `ondrop` to `drop`, add `e.stopPropagation()`, change `holder` to `elem`.

```
edo.directive('fileDrag', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem) {
      elem.bind('drop', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e..stopPropagation();
        var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0], reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (event) {
          console.log(event.target);
          elem.style.background = 'url(' + event.target.result + ') no-repeat center';
        };
        console.log(file);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        return false;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

I was doing something similar and here is my working solution:

HTML

```js
app.directive("dropzone", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        link: function (scope, elem) {
            elem.bind('drop', function(evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                evt.preventDefault();

                var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
                for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);

                    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                        return function(e) {
                            var newFile = { name : theFile.name,
                                type : theFile.type,
                                size : theFile.size,
                                lastModifiedDate : theFile.lastModifiedDate
                            }

                            scope.addfile(newFile);
                        };
                    })(f);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```css
div[dropzone] {
    border: 2px dashed #bbb;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font: 20pt bold;
    color: #bbb;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div dropzone>Drop Files Here</div>
```

Comment: No, Dropzone doesn't play nice with angular

Comment: I've just used your piece of code to create a plnkr, and i got no luck with it. Can you help to point what is the problem with it?http://plnkr.co/edit/C7Vv8d?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for this. I know this is a older post but straight out of the box I only had 1 problem. Getting the file info I had to traverse a bit different.

`var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; Change To  var files = evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution.

Comment: In order for this to work in Chrome, you now need to prevent default on the 'dragover' event. You can use code like this:

      `element.bind('dragover', ($event) => {
        $event.preventDefault()
        $event.stopPropagation()
      })`

Answer (score 8):

Preventing default events, and getting file from original event. All can be implemented in directive. You should pass function, for work with files to attribute on-file-drop. Also 'dragging' class is added to dropzone element while dragging.
In view it looks like this:

```
<div file-dropzone on-file-drop="myFunction">This is my dropzone </div>
```

directive:

```
function fileDropzoneDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: fileDropzoneLink
    };
    function fileDropzoneLink($scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('dragover', processDragOverOrEnter);
        element.bind('dragenter', processDragOverOrEnter);
        element.bind('dragend', endDragOver);
        element.bind('dragleave', endDragOver);
        element.bind('drop', dropHandler);

        function dropHandler(angularEvent) {

            var event = angularEvent.originalEvent || angularEvent;
            var file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
            event.preventDefault();
            $scope.$eval(attrs.onFileDrop)(file);

        }
        function processDragOverOrEnter(angularEvent) {
            var event = angularEvent.originalEvent || angularEvent;
            if (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
            element.addClass('dragging');
            return false;
        }

        function endDragOver() {
            element.removeClass('dragging');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice answer. Just one thing, I had to call endDragOver at the end of dropHandler to remove the dragging effect once the file is processed.