# Drop event did not work as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I am trying to write a directive to support dragdrop for file upload, and i don't want to use any 3rd libs.
I find a post regarding this topic on the SO:

[AngularJS file drag and drop in directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712463/angularjs-file-drag-and-drop-in-directive)

I create a plnkr according to above post, and i got no luck with it, can anyone help to point it out what's the problem with my plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/C7Vv8d?p=preview

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive("dropzone", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        link: function (scope, elem) {
            elem.bind('drop', function(evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                evt.preventDefault();
                window.console.log('listener worked!');
                var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
                for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);

                    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                        return function(e) {
                            var newFile = { name : theFile.name,
                                type : theFile.type,
                                size : theFile.size,
                                lastModifiedDate : theFile.lastModifiedDate
                            }

                            //scope.addfile(newFile);
                        };
                    })(f);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
})();
```

Comment: @cojomojo did you really look into my question, i said i create the plnkr based on the post you just find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u already got the file uploaded , see `console.log(newFile);` log out in console

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.directive("dropzone", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      link: function(scope, elem) {
        elem.bind('dragover', function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
        });
        elem.bind('dragenter', function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.divClass = 'on-drag-enter';
          });
        });
        elem.bind('dragleave', function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.divClass = '';
          });
        });
        elem.bind('drop', function(evt) {
          evt.stopPropagation();
          evt.preventDefault();
          window.console.log('listener worked!');
          var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
          for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);

            reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
              console.log(theFile);
              return function(e) {
                var newFile = {
                  name: theFile.name,
                  type: theFile.type,
                  size: theFile.size,
                  lastModifiedDate: theFile.lastModifiedDate
                }
                console.log(newFile);
                //scope.addfile(newFile);
              };
            })(f);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: Yes, i forgot to bind 'dragover', 'dragleave', and 'dragenter'.