# Jquery: doesn't support drop event?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I want add a event handler to `drop` event, my first try is to use jquery 1.9.1

```
var dropIt = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.dataTransfer);
    e.stopPropagation();  
    e.preventDefault(); 
}

     $('#drop-area').on('drop',dropIt);
```

but this can't print the `e.dataTransfer`, when I use the origin:

```
$('#drop-area')[0].addEventListener('drop', dropIt, false);
```

it can work?

why this happen?

Comment: did you import jquery-ui?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [using jquery .on for drop events when uploading files from the desktop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544977/using-jquery-on-for-drop-events-when-uploading-files-from-the-desktop)

Comment: @KyelJmD: I don't want use the jquery ui, I want use html5 drag and drop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery does not automatically normalize the `dataTransfer` property, you'll have to do it manually. E.g.

```
jQuery.event.props.push("dataTransfer");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).on('drop','#drop-area',dropIt);
```

**OR**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #div1 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function allowDrop(ev)
            {
                ev.preventDefault();
            }

            function drag(ev)
            {
                ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
            }

            function drop(ev)
            {
                ev.preventDefault();
                var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>
        <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        <br />
        <img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
    </body>
</html>
```