# add drag & drop to traditional file input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a traditional upload form (no upload plugins or AJAX submission).  I'm hoping to add a drop target that will cover the whole page, like you see on sites like http://imgur.com, but I don't want to redesign the entire user flow.

Is there a simple plugin to display a modal overlay when a file is dragged over the screen, and then populate the input element when it's dropped, and fire the change event?  If not, how would I go about writing such a thing?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? SO is a place to get your code fixed, this question is so broad that it will likely get downvoted and closed.

Comment: @JayBlanchard This doesn't seem like a broad question at all.  Maybe I don't understand what you mean.  I see answers like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544977/using-jquery-on-for-drop-events-when-uploading-files-from-the-desktop), that grab a file on drop, but they end up with a javascript array of files.  Instead, I need to populate an input[type=file] field.  I am trying to get some idea of how to approach this, and as such, I don't have demo code yet.

Comment: You're asking the SO community to find a plugin for you or to write your code.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think you might be confused about what stackoverflow is.  Here is the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about), **Coding Techniques** is clearly expected.  I have spent two days researching how drag works in browser, and have found only AJAX solutions.  So I asked a clear and simple question. "how do you do it without AJAX?"  If the answer is "You Can't", that's fine, but how am I supposed to show my code if I don't know what approach to take?  This is an incredibly common need that is under-documented.  I am not asking for someone to write my code, but for a direction.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on the jQuery website? BTW, this is in the About Page: "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do."

Comment: jQuery, on its own, only goes so far as to provide `.bind("ondrop", callback(e))`.  It doesn't provide any documentation on processing the resulting event

Comment: Here is a tutorial that shows the basics of handling an event - http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/03/jquery-drag-and-drop-tutorial.html

Comment: @JayBlanchard, that tutorial deals with draggable elements in jqueryui, not file drag and drop.  seriously man, you aren't helping.  I need someone who has dealt with drag and drop uploads.

Comment: http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload

Comment: @JayBlanchard, and that is a non-jQuery tutorial, using XHR/AJAX to upload, which is exactly what I said I wanted to avoid.

Comment: How about this? http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/08/file-uploader/ Of course, you could be Googling for the same things I am, so if you are I'll stop.

Comment: @JayBlanchard pretty sure I've seen all that google has to offer... this one also uses an AJAX request to process the files.

Comment: Alrighty. My apologies for not being any better at being able to help you. Perhaps you can try to code something that will work, and if it doesn't you can come back to SO, post the code and then we can try to help you figure out any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a LOT of research, I've found that this is an impossibility, as the FILE input type is read-only to javascript, in modern browsers, for security reasons.  Because of this limitation, AJAX-style requests are the ONLY way to perform drag-and-drop uploads.