# HTML: Is it possible to create popup after a drag and drop of a file for upload?

Tags: html, file, upload, drag

I'm working on a webapp that is not AJAX-based. I have implemented a drag and drop functionality for file uploads but, as expected, the transfer gets cancelled if the user clicks on any link. Is it possible to create a drag and drop functionality so that a popup is created and the file transfer is handled in that window, letting the user continue using the webapp?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a function in JQuery which detects ondrop events and lets you run function while true(detects ondrop)

[using jquery .on for drop events when uploading files from the desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544977/using-jquery-on-for-drop-events-when-uploading-files-from-the-desktop)

u can read more about it here, maybe it wil help