# Append Drag & Drop File to Input or Convert it to Base64

Tags: jquery, html, fileapi

I got an working example of how to drag drop and preview an image using HTML5 file API ([html5's file api example with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722500/html5s-file-api-example-with-jquery)). My interest is to create an image upload form that will use AJAX to post back to the server.

What I am interested in knowing is, if there is a way we could append drag and drop files to an `

Or...

Is it possible to kind of convert the file to Base64 and append it to an hidden input field?

I am not interested in Cross Browser support, I am feeling sick of even hearing the term now :(.

I am very new to jQuery and JS so it will be a plus if you can explain with a little info.

Comment: look into jQuery file upload plugins...simple google search

Comment: I actually need to upload the file with a form, along with the form data some things need to be done to the image... I am currently doing this in multiple steps, but would like to do it one step. For that I would need to pass the selected image in to the form. Necessity to preview before upload is a must.

Comment: file upload plugins work from form. If you want to AJAX submit form data you will need hidden Iframe to manage image upload...plugins have been heavily used , tested and debugged